# Angular E2E- Is it possible to call an 'It' function in a loop?

Tags: angularjs

This works

```
it('should create a report for index: ', function() {
    var dataLength = window.test.parameters.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++){
        var parameterObject = window.test.parameters[i];
        var propNumber = parameterObject.propertyNumber;
        element(":contains('" + propNumber + "')").click();
        element(":button('View')").click();
        expect(element('div *:contains(' + reportName + ')').count()).toEqual(4);
    }
});
```

This does not

```
var dataLength = window.test.parameters.length;
for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++){
    it('should create a report for index: ', function() {
        var parameterObject = window.test.parameters[i];
        var propNumber = parameterObject.propertyNumber;
        element(":contains('" + propNumber + "')").click();
        element(":button('View')").click();
        expect(element('div *:contains(' + reportName + ')').count()).toEqual(4);
    });
};
```

My intention is to parameterize this test to run it many times with different combinations of parameters each time.
I've tried removing var and 'use strict'; to make sure i is global.  I've tried declaring i outside of the 'describe' function.  Is there a trick to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`it` may be async, try to lexically scope it.

```
var dataLength = window.test.parameters.length;
for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++){
    it('should create a report for index: ', function(i) {
        return function () {
            var parameterObject = window.test.parameters[i];
            var propNumber = parameterObject.propertyNumber;
            element(":contains('" + propNumber + "')").click();
            element(":button('View')").click();
            expect(element('div *:contains(' + reportName + ')').count()).toEqual(4);
        };
    }(i));
};
```

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly!  And thanks for the fast Answer!